# How to merge Two Vertex details and Edge Properties details Together in a single gremlin query

Tags: gremlin, vertex, edges, rexster

How to merge Two Vertex details and Edge Properties details Together in a single gremlin query.

I'm having two Vertices :

UserInfo vertex
[image]

PostInfo vertex 
[image]

EdgeInfo Between them
[image]

With Gremlin Query : g.v(2569472).out('_label','WallPost')[0..1]

[image]

I'm getting UserPost Vertex details , i want to add UserVertex detail in the response (i.e gender ) and Edge property detail in the response (i.e EdgeMessage)

I'm trying to compare sql equivalent innerjoin operation with gremlin from [sql2gremlin](http://sql2gremlin.com/#_inner_join) but i'm not able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL2Gremlin](http://sql2gremlin.com) is written for TinkerPop 3, you're still using TinkerPop 2 (which is a lot more complicated IMO). Anyway, here's how you would do it in TP2:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.v(1).outE("knows")
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
gremlin> g.v(1).outE("knows").inV().retain([g.v(4)])
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.v(1).as("x").outE("knows").as("y").inV().retain([g.v(4)]).select(["x","y"]) {it.map()} {it.weight}
==>[x:{name=marko, age=29}, y:1.0]
```